# UIInteractiveTransition and making transition become interactive again

Tags: ios, user-interface

I have a UIInteractiveTransition using a UIPanGesture which calls finishTransition or cancelTransition when it is finished.

However would there be a way to tell iOS the user has started panning again and you would like for it to cancel animating the view controller using the non-interactive portion of the transition and allow you to update manually ?

Comment: The user has started panning again through a different gesture recogniser object?

Comment: No its the only gesture recogniser.

Comment: So started panning again means what exactly? Because if anytime the user lifts their finger, cancel/finish state is reached. And if he simply flips the direction, the code should automatically take care of that by updating the interaction with the required percentage value.

Comment: So the view is animating out after they lift their finger, I want them to be able to catch the view and be able to swipe it in the other direction if need be. However as soon as you call finishTransition it seems thats it, there is no way back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the finish/cancel transition after a delay with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and within that time if the gesture callback is received again, cancel the selector, and update the same instance of `UIInteractiveTransition` with the required percentage. Seems like this should do what you want.